# Automating updating custom post in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

In Wordpress I am using the LearnPress plugin. This plugin creates custom posts (to my knowledge) called `lp_lesson`. I am also using a plugin called Advanced Custom Fields PRO. This plugin allows the creation of additional fields on each of the `lp_lesson`. The custom field I added has a name (which I am guessing is the variable name) of `wpk_role_options`.

What I would like to do is come up with a `for-loop` that loops through each `lp_lesson` and checks the `category` associated with that lessons using a `switch` or `if else`. If the condition is met I would like to add text to the `wpk_role_options` custom field.

I think I have the logic complete for the most part, but it's more of the syntax that has me stumped.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

What I have gathered so far:

```
<?php
//Get post type of lp_lesson
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'lp_lesson'
    );
    $post_query = new WP_Query($args);

    //Categories of lp_lesson
    $categories = get_categories($args);

if($post_query->have_posts() ) {
  while($post_query->have_posts() ) {
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        if (in_category('Test', $post_query)){
            //change wpk_role_options from lesson
        }
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you try searching on Google `for loop in php`

Comment: I do know the logic behind it. It's more of the variables. Like how do I access the `wpk_role_options` text, the `category`, and loop through `lp_lesson`. Let me post what I have so far and maybe that'll help more.

Comment: Definitely more code examples will help.

Comment: I do believe I am going in the right direction.

Comment: @Torewin When are you running this code? When the post is saved by the admin? Or when you user views the post on the front end? Or what?

Comment: I am wanting to run this code once when I log on. I have over 1,000 of these posts and I need to add text to the custom field in each one of them (different for each category). Moving forward I can manually do it, but I figured I could just run a quick function so I wouldn't have to open up each of them.

Comment: By the way, it's not the best practice to move helpful answers into your question. You should just leave your question text alone (unless you want to clarify something) and accept the helpful answer and upvote as well.

Comment: You typed faster then I could. I was hoping you could just confirm that the category removal was what you meant and that I would replace `$cat->term_id` with my category name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the "WordPress loop" syntax which is used to display post lists on the public side. However, you wouldn't really want to use that on the admin side.

You need to use a normal php loop. You would also probably want to use the faster and easier `get_posts` function:

```
//Get post type of lp_lesson
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'lp_lesson'
);
$posts = get_posts($args);

$categories = get_categories();

for($posts as $post) {

    foreach($categories as $cat) {
       if ( in_category( $cat->term_id, $post) ){
          // This post has the category 
       }
    }

    // get/check for a post custom field
    $field_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'meta_name', 1);

    // or you can also update this post's custom field
    update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'meta_name', 'new_value' );

  }
}
```

I don't really know why you are looping through the categories. If you are only checking for a specific category, you can take out the whole foreach around the $categories thing.

Comment: I plan to do something with every category found. Instead of the `foreach` I can just start my `switch` instead? Also, would you be able to solve the last part? Add/modifying text from a custom field on each of theses posts?

Comment: Yeah, if you want to do something specific with category A and something different with category B, then a switch is probably your best bet. You can take out the `get_categories` line in that case as well.

Comment: @Torewin sure I added some helpful functions to my answer.

Comment: Could you confirm that the modified code is what you were talking about when removing the category?

Comment: @Torewin, yes that's right. But you shouldn't move answers into your question. That's just confusing for everyone. Instead just accept the answer that helps you.

Comment: Thanks! I was just having it there so you were able to see it. You're a life savior man! Just saved me over 35 hours of work!